# Have `NextMethod` invoke implicit method even when explicit class present

Tags: r, oop

I wish to dispatch against explicit and implicit classes.  Here we create an implicit class method (`s3fun.integer`), and explicit method (`s3fun.explicit`), and a default method:

```
s3fun.integer <- function(x) "Integer"
s3fun.explicit <- function(x) { cat("Dispatching\n"); NextMethod() }
s3fun.default <- function(x) "Default"
s3fun <- function(x) UseMethod("s3fun")
```

If we try this with an object of implicit class "integer", this works as expected:

```
s3fun(1:3)
# [1] "Integer"
```

However, if we try with an object that has the same implicit class, but also has an explicit class, the `NextMethod` call skips over the implicit method and goes straight to the default:

```
s3fun(structure(1:3, class="explicit"))
# Dispatching
# [1] "Default"         # doesn't dispatch `s3fun.integer`
```

I'm able to work around with a hack in the default:

```
s3fun.default <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(attr(x, "class"))) return("Default")
  do.call(.Generic, list(unclass(x)))
}
s3fun(structure(1:3, class="explicit"))
# Dispatching
# [1] "Integer"
```

but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

S3 classes can be formed into a linear hierarchy. `class="explicit"` means that there is no class hierarchy, so the 'next' method must be the default. On the other hand, `class=c("explicit", "integer")` provides a linear hierarchy and the 'next' class after explicit is 'integer' (and then default). Thus

```
s3fun(structure(1:3, class=c("explicit", "integer")))
```

I guess the usual paradigm when imposing a class hierarchy on an object is `class(x) = c("foo", class(x))`

Comment: Thanks Martin.  Something I should have made clear is that I don't actually have control of the objects being submitted to my methods.  I could add `class=c(class(x), typeof(x))` in all methods, but then I would require logic to make sure this has not already been done by a prior method (plus need to handle things such as matrices).  This seems more complicated than my workaround.